# How can I set environment variable WORKON_HOME for virtualenvwrapper-win

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to setup virtualenvwrapper-win on a usb drive as part of a python development environment. In https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win it states:

```
Optional: Add an environment variable WORKON_HOME to specify the path to store environments. By default, this is %USERPROFILE%\Envs.
```

but doesn't explain how to do this. Could someone help with this?

My system python is at:

```
/f/python27/python
```

Comment: Are you using msys or something?  Really all you're asking I think is how to set an environment variable...

Comment: Yes - git-bash on win7

Comment: I think this can help. http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html

Comment: Hi Raydel, I appreciate the tip. I've read the documentation and googled for examples ( not finding much ), but being new to python, I'm not sure I understand how to use the site module in this case . Can you elaborate please? - Bill

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AS lguananut said, you are asking how to set an environment variable.
Take Win7 as example,

1. execute command "sysdm.cpl"
2. Go to Advanced tab, open "Enviroment Variables..."
3. New a system variable
4. In pop window, set variable name = WORKON_HOME, value = [your virtual environments root]

relaunch one command prompt, all commands like mkvirtualenv, workon will works.

Comment: I can see how to change the WORKON_HOME env var in Windows, I'm wondering how it sets the default to the 'Env' directory in my user directory? It's not defined in my current set of environment variables. Would be interesting to know!

Comment: take a look at workon.bat that is in Scripts folder after you install virtualnenvwrapper-win. It will call activate.bat that will set variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer **Powershell** like me, you could also try the following code.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("WORKON_HOME", "C:\Venv", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PROJECT_HOME", "C:\Project", "User")
```

It will create two environment variables for your **current user**:

- WORKON_HOME
- PROJECT_HOME

Paste the sample code in PowerShell window:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("WORKON_HOME", "<Your-Virtual-Environment-Root>", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PROJECT_HOME", "<Your-Project-Root>", "User")
```

It will populate the variables like

[image: Windows Environment Variable Configuration Result]

Hope it helps.